# Dracut - what is it and why does it suddenly run without reboot?

Tags: rhel, dracut

I see that dracut has been run on my system (RHEL 9) during the weekend, and it seems like it has changed my authselect configuration messing up SSH connections.

After some searching I've found that:

> What is the use of dracut? Dracut is a set of tools that provide
> enhanced functionality for automating the Linux boot process. The tool
> named dracut is used to create a Linux boot image (initramfs) by
> copying tools and files from an installed system and combining it with
> the Dracut framework, which is usually found in
> /usr/lib/dracut/modules.

It was run using: `dracut -f`

```
dracut: drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root            0 Mar 21 10:23 etc/authselect
```

**Question:** Why has this happened, and which process decides "now I'll run dracut"? The machine has not been rebooted.

Comment: Was there a kernel update?

Comment: How can I verify and check this? Checking `/boot` doesn't show anything on those dates, except the creating of initramfs.img  which is what the dracut command does, right?

Comment: The package management logs should have that information